# What is procedure to make token.json against credentials.json for different user, to use Google Spread sheet API's?

Tags: php, google-sheets

I implemented Google spread sheet API's for a project in which i have to run cron job at midnight to update google sheet.
Because i was new to Google spread sheet API first i used Quick start example using my email, create a project, provide a sheet id, credentials.json and make token.json after run my file.

Before creating token.json, i have to run my file in cmd then copy url, paste into browser and hit that url, that url create a token which i have to paste in cmd which create token.json.

I have complete all these step above and run my project perfectly.

Now i have to deliver this project to client i have asked him to provide me a credential.json file which he provide me but now i have to create token.json file which i can't because client have different gmail id.

Now please suggest me what should i do, i have credetials.json file.

Code for google spread sheet API :

```
public function getClient()
    {
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setApplicationName('Google Sheets API PHP Quickstart');
        $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS);
        $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
        $client->setAccessType('offline');
        $credentialsPath = 'token.json';
        if (file_exists($credentialsPath)) {
            $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($credentialsPath), true);
        } else {
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
            print 'Enter verification code: ';
            $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
            if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
            }
            if (!file_exists(dirname($credentialsPath))) {
                mkdir(dirname($credentialsPath), 0700, true);
            }
            file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($accessToken));
            printf("Credentials saved to %s\n", $credentialsPath);
        }
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
        if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
            $jsonCred = file_get_contents($credentialsPath);
            $jsonArray = json_decode($jsonCred, true);
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($jsonArray["refresh_token"]);
            $newAccessToken = $client->getAccessToken();
            $accessToken = array_merge($jsonArray, $newAccessToken);
            file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($accessToken));
        }
        return $client;
    }
```

Comment: were u able to get the token.json?

Comment: as per tutorial "i have to run my file in cmd then copy url, paste into browser and hit that url, that url create a token which i have to paste in cmd which create token.json"

Comment: Yes it did work for me finally

Comment: you are also doing by using terminal ?

Comment: I was first using jupyter notebook and it was failing repeatedly, then I changed to command prompt (windows) and it worked.